# How to deploy cms pages in a multi environment setup

Tags: magento-enterprise, cms

If our business users create cms pages in a dedicated dev environment.

How would we deploy those pages to staging and then production?

Comment: I would be curious to know if you found a solution for this in the end?

Comment: We avoided the dedicated dev environment for cms pages. We let our content writers write in the production environment. We backed up the database. We also downloaded the database into the dev environment whenever we needed it. So basically we reversed the direction for cms. Instead of going from dev to prod. We went from prod to dev.